# Annoying warning message while doing Ctrl + c on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

It's been a while I have been getting a warning message that pops up on Excel when I do `Ctrl + c` or `right click` + copy

The message says:

**There's a problem with the clipboard, but you can still paste your content within this workbook**

This issue doesn't happen every time I do `Ctrl + c`, I don't know how to get rid off it

Any idea on how to resolve this ?

Enable live preview is already unchecked and it still has the problem.

Comment: Enable live preview is alteady unchecked and it doesn't solve the problem. Thx

Comment: Please click on `edit` above and at left, and add to your original post that File | Options | General and unchecking Enable Live Preview. did not solve the problem, so that useful information is added to where others can see it easily. Comments pile up and information in them gets lost.

Comment: This happens when another app has a lock on the system clipboard. Microsoft says "In this situation you can still paste within Excel.  However you cannot paste to another app like Word or Outlook which uses the clipboard." https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_365hp/theres-a-problem-with-the-clipboard-but-you-can/6720299f-1084-4104-93cc-abee9dcf7469  Do you have Word or other Office apps open when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I have that since years, and it seems to happen when I am 'too fast' with a sequence of activities (but only under Windows 10).

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again, then it should work.

if this does not help, you might have another application running in the background, which feels entitled to mess with the clipboard. Disable anything else until the perpetrator is identified.